# Object out of scope in deferred?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm making some tests to try to learn a little bit more about deferreds. So, I made an ajax web navigation:

```
$('ul#nav a').on('click', function(e){          
    var hash = $(this).attr('href');
    check(hash).fail(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
function check(hash){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if (!hash) {                
        hash = window.location.hash;
    }
    if (!hash) {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var file = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        hash = file.replace(extension,'');
    }
    if (hash !== prev_url){
        prev_url= hash;
        loadPage(hash).done(
            function(data){ 
                var html = $(data);
                var filtered= html.find('#content');
                content.html(filtrado.html());
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        ).fail(function(){ // Url doesn't exist
            content.html('<p>Page does not exist!</p>');
            deferred.reject();                  
        });
    }
    return deferred;
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine except the check.fail function has no access to the event object so I'm unable to prevent the page change and so, it fails.

Comment: Can we see `loadPage()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fail` callback closes over `e` (it is a closure) so it definitely should have access (or do you get an error?).

The problem is likely that at the moment the `fail` callback is executed (some time later as you are doing an Ajax request, which is *asynchronous*), the event handling is already completed. Calling `e.preventDefault()` does not have any effect anymore.

---

You need to do `e.preventDefault();` straight after the click and assume the page doesn't exist until the asynchronous Deferred events tell you otherwise.

```
$('ul#nav a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  // Assume bad link until otherwise proven
    var hash = $(this).attr('href');
    check(hash).done(function(){
       window.location.href = hash; // Good hash, let's go to that
    });
});
```